# Neoclipse unable to produce graph view, show reference node error?

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j, neoclipse

I'm having some trouble using Neoclipse with my Neo4j server. I can connect to the db without any issues but as soon as the connection is established it throws two error boxes simultaneously.

[image: error dialogue 1]

[image: error dialogue 2]

If I click `OK` and continue I'm presented with an empty database graph view.

If I click the home icon to show reference node I'm getting this error:

[image]

After reading around it seems it might be something to do with the reference node at location zero but I'm not sure whether this was even created in this version of Neo4j (3.0.3); it's not present. I read that this approach was deprecated or even removed?

Do I need to create a reference node in order to be able to use Neoclipse?
If so how do I do so? I'm interacting with the db in java using the neo4j-java-driver.

**Thanks for any help and advice!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of neo4j (some time after 2.3.x) started enforcing the requirement that nodes (in Cypher) be specified within parentheses.

[neoclipse](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neoclipse) was last updated 2 years ago to conform to neo4j 2.1.4, and does not always use parentheses for nodes when making Cypher queries. So, it will not work with neo4j 3.x.

If you need to use neoclipse, you would either have to modify its code, or downgrade your neo4j service to an [older version](https://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. Do you have any suggestions for software similar to Neoclipse that is relatively straight forward to use with Neo4j? I've seen Gephi suggested but the Neo4j plugin is for 0.8.2. I'm on Mac and found Gephi to be very unstable. Further the 0.8.2 version doesn't run past the boot display so it makes not an option.